# mysql join the same table multiple times with group by

Tags: mysql, left-join

i have table `products` (`id`, `name`, `price`, ...) and `productStats` (`productId`, `time`, `unitsSold`, `unitsReserved`, ...).

In `productStats` we have row for each minute and all necesary aggregate values for that one particular minute. If we need to get stats for one period it is ok:

```
select 
    id,
    name,
    SUM(lastDay.unitsSold) as latDayUnitsSold,
from `products`

left join 
    `productStats` as `lastDay` 
    on `products`.`id` = `lastDay`.`productId` 
    and `lastDay`.`time` between '2018-05-27 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'

group by `products`.`id`
```

But we encountered error (wrong values), when we want to get aggregate values for multipe periods at the same time:

```
select 
    id,
    name,
    SUM(lastDay.unitsSold) as latDayUnitsSold,
    SUM(lastMonth.unitsSold) as latMonthUnitsSold,
    SUM(lastYear.unitsSold) as latYearUnitsSold,
from `products`

left join 
    `productStats` as `lastDay` 
    on `products`.`id` = `lastDay`.`productId` 
    and `lastDay`.`time` between '2018-05-27 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'

left join 
    `productStats` as `lastMonth` 
    on `products`.`id` = `lastMonth`.`productId` 
    and `lastDay`.`time` between '2018-04-28 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'

left join 
    `productStats` as `lastYear` 
    on `products`.`id` = `lastYear`.`productId` 
    and `lastDay`.`time` between '2017-05-28 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'

group by `products`.`id`
```

How can we join the same table multiple times, but with different datetime ranges and have seperate sum column for each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the different conditions in the same join table using `OR`

```
select 
    id,
    name,
    SUM(lastDay.unitsSold) as latDayUnitsSold,
    SUM(lastMonth.unitsSold) as latMonthUnitsSold,
    SUM(lastYear.unitsSold) as latYearUnitsSold,
from `products`

left join 
    `productStats` as `lastDay` 
    on `products`.`id` = `lastDay`.`productId` 
    and 
    (
     `lastDay`.`time` between '2018-05-27 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'
      OR
     `lastDay`.`time` between '2018-04-28 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'
      OR 
      `lastDay`.`time` between '2017-05-28 00:00:00' and '2018-05-28 00:00:00'
    )
group by `products`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation for different time range using single join operation

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `lastDay`.`time` BETWEEN '2018-05-27 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-28 00:00:00' THEN lastDay.unitsSold ELSE 0 END) AS latDayUnitsSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `lastDay`.`time` BETWEEN '2018-04-28 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-28 00:00:00' THEN lastDay.unitsSold ELSE 0 END) AS latMonthUnitsSold,
    SUM(lastDay.unitsSold) AS latYearUnitsSold,
FROM  `products` p
LEFT JOIN
    `productStats` AS `lastDay` 
    ON p.`id` = `lastDay`.`productId` 
    AND `lastDay`.`time` BETWEEN '2017-05-28 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-28 00:00:00'
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```